# Bose-Einstein condensate effect

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter, bose-einstein-condensate, quantum-statistics

Does every boson gas go through the condensate effect? Could there be a  boson gas with high energy (photons for example) that would have enough energy to be at different quantum states even at 0 K?

Comment: So, are you asking if it is possible for a system of bosons to avoid Bose-Einstein condensation up to absolute $0$?

Comment: yes, could you have a boson gas that avoids the condensation even if its cooled to 0K?

Comment: like a free particle (with 0 spin) with a lot of kinetic energy that even at 0K has enough energy to be at different quantum states?

Comment: The condensation only happens for massive bosons. A massless field always moves at the speed of light. Having said that... it might well be that the electromagnetic field does have a tiny rest mass.

Comment: The BEC phase is not stable for attractively interacting particles. About photons, BEC of photons had been achieved but for this, people had to generate "*effective* interactions" between the photons by use of a non-linear medium (dye medium).